# NextJS - Linter with lint-staged not working

Tags: next.js

I've set up lint-staged and husky with NextJS. When we run `yarn lint`, it calls `yarn next lint` under the hood and it works. When we call `yarn lint-staged`, we receive an error:

```
✖ yarn lint:
> Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
```

The point is that `pages` directory exists under `src` and it should work. What is going on?

*package.json:*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "yarn lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use "eslint" instead of "yarn lint" under lint-staged.

I believe next lint has some inherent configurations that aren't compatible with lint-staged.

"eslint" catches the intended error during pre-commits

*package.json*

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint"
    ]
  }
}
```